# Linux Desktop VDI from thin client

Tags: virtualization

I checked VDI Solutions Like VMware Horizon, Citrix Etc. all gives  Windows VDI.
Is there any solution I can load Ubuntu Desktop Or Centos Desktop image from any thin Client

Comment: RedHat and VERDE have VDI products, and there is also NX.

Comment: AFAIK there is no solution for Linux Desktops but you could check out Ubuntu LTSP.